# How can I solve this defined integration in an efficient way?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x \arctan(x)}{e^x+1}dx
$$
I'm having a hard time trying to find a solution. I considered making a new function and I also tried to make use of the fact that $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$ so I could simplify the expression but nothing works. I don't know how to get rid of $e^x$ without complications.

I would be more than happy to receive some ideas.

Comment: This integral is not likely solvable by elementary functions.  You may be able to find a good numerical approximation.

Comment: No elementary antiderivative, sure. But the integral does have a nice closed form, $\frac{\pi-2}4$.

Comment: It's the right answer, yes, but I'm not sure how to approximate it. Is the Midpoint Rule helpful in this case?

Comment: Note the symmetric bounds, and the use of odd and even functions. There are some symmetries here that we can take advantage of: split the bounds of integration into an integral from $-1$ to $0$ and an integral from $0$ to $1.$ Now use the substitution $u = -x$ on either integral (I would do the integral where $x$ is negative) and look at what happens. If you do it right, you should end up with an integral you can handle with integration by parts. (although there are some sneaky manipulations inbetween I've glazed over)

Comment: @Lauraa Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 8):

Noticing that $\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{e^x
+1} =1 - \frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1} $ and that $\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}$ is odd, we get
$\require{\cancel}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x}{e^x+1}\arctan(x) \, \mathrm{d}x &=\frac{\cancel{\color{purple}{2}}}{\cancel{\color{blue}{2}}}\int_{\color{purple}{0}}^{1}\underbrace{x \arctan(x)}_{\color{purple}{\text{even}}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^2 +1 \right)' \arctan(x)  \, \mathrm{d}x \\
& \overset{\text{I.B.P.}}{=} \frac{1}{\cancel{2}}\left(\cancel{1^2 +1} \right)\arctan(1)- \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cancel{x^2+1}}{\cancel{x^2+1}}\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Just a note, you can handle the integral of $\frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1}$ a bit more directly by noting that $\frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{x^2 + 1 - 1}{x^2 + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan, thank you for the suggestion! I've made an edit simplifying the answer using your idea.